# Geometry: Alpha Shape formation of 2D points

Tags: python, algorithm, math, geometry, linear-algebra

The project I have been working on recently involves constructing an alpha shape of 2D points and calculating the area of the polygon formed by the boundary points of the alpha shape.

**workflow of my project:**

1. Receive 2D points as input.
2. Construct the alpha shape of the 2D points using the Python alphashape library.
3. Calculate the boundary points.
4. Calculate the area of the polygon consisting of the boundary points using the shapely polygon.area function.

**Some problem on the project:**

Sometimes I receive 2D points like the ones shown in fig 1. When I try to construct an alpha shape of these points, two Multi Polygons are generated as shown in fig 2. However, this does not allow me to calculate the area that I am interested in. The result I want is shown in fig 3.

Is there a way to interpolate the data from fig 1 to construct an alpha shape like the one shown in fig 3? I would appreciate any advice or opinions.

**example data image:**
[image]

**example what I get real image:**
[image]

**example what I want image:**
[image]

**What i tried before example code:**
[sample code I tried before](https://github.com/dohyeonYoon/alphashape/blob/main/sample.py)

Comment: The result that you want, in the last figure, actually looks much, much easier to obtain than an alpha-shape. Alpha-shapes require relatively-complex algorithms and are used in cases where convex hulls are not satisfying. But the result in your last figure is a convex hull. So you don't need an alpha-shape algorithm at all. Just use a convex hull algorithm.

Comment: @Stef I was only looking for algorithms that are too complex. I solved it with convex hull. thank you so much!